# How to fix "Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of <child component>" if ContentChildren used

Tags: angular

I tried to implement ContentChildren scenario of Angular in my sample app. **For ContentChild it works but for ContentChildren it throws error in console**. In child component, I have used input property of type String and same is being referred.

**1) ng-content template html (footer.component.html) file**

```
<div>
  <ng-content>
  </ng-content>
  hello test from content
</div>
```

**2) conent projection snippet in dashboard.component.html**

```
<app-footer>
  <app-child *ngFor="let mes of messages" [childMessage]="mes">
  </app-child>
</app-footer>
```

**3) child component - child.component.html**

```
<p>
  Say {{ childMessage }}
</p>
```

**4) child component class - child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() childMessage : string = 'abc';

  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**console error -**

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of
>   'app-child'.
>   1. If 'app-child' is an Angular component and it has 'ngForOf' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-child' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("    </app-child> -->
>   ]*ngFor="let mes of messages"
>   [childMessage]="mes">
>           "): ng:///DashboardModule/DashboardComponent.html@18:13 Property binding
>   ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure
>   that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are
>   listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("    </app-child> -->   [ERROR
>   ->]

Comment: Could you add the code of your app.module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to import the *common* module.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    // .....
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I forgot to import common module. I then referred https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use ng-template to wrap around the child component.

```
<ng-template *ngFor="let mes of messages" >
  <app-child  [childMessage]="mes">
  </app-child>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks Sachila for your input. it was issue of CommonModule I missed. It works without ng-template. with ng-template, data is not rendering.